# How to display records in view based on their first letter?

Tags: laravel, model-view-controller, eloquent, laravel-blade

In my controller I am passing to a view a bunch of categories in alphabetical order like this :

```
public function index()
    {
        $categories = Category::orderBy('name', 'asc')->get();

        return view('categories')->with('categories',$categories);
    }
```

In my view, I want to display in separate columns corresponding to letters from the alphabet each of these categories, so in column "A" I will have all categories starting with A and so on.

Is it possible to filter the results in the view by letter in order to achieve this, and if yes, how can it be done?

Answer (score 7):

You can group the list of categories by first letter in your controller and then pass the result to your view, here is how to do:

**Controller:**

```
public function index() {

    $categories = Category::orderBy('name', 'asc')->get();

    $groups = $categories->reduce(function ($carry, $category) {

        // get first letter
        $first_letter = $category['name'][0];

        if ( !isset($carry[$first_letter]) ) {
            $carry[$first_letter] = [];
        }

        $carry[$first_letter][] = $category;

        return $carry;

    }, []);

    return view('categories')->with('groups', $groups);
}
```

**View:**

```
@foreach($groups as $letter => $group)

    <ul>

        <li>{{ $letter }}</li>

        @foreach($group as $category)

            <li>{{ $category['name'] }}</li>

        @endforeach

    </ul>

@endforeach
```

Here is a working [example](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/26a1f007e2e58d0b3964b40dbaff854677b04c21) using [array_reduce](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php) (it's the same as [Collection::reduce](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#method-reduce) function above)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to load from database only categories with a specified first letter:

```
$categories = Category::where('name', 'like', 'A%')->orderBy('name', 'asc')->get();
```

If you want to load all categories and then filter them, use `filter()` method:

```
@foreach ('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ' as $letter)
    @foreach ($categories->filter(function($i) use($letter) { return starts_with($i->name, $letter); }) as $category)
        {{ $category->name }}
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Comment: No, I want to filter them in the view. If I load them like this they are not going to be in alphabetical order. And I will need a big amount of variables in the controller. So I just want to filter them in the view based on their first letter when they are already in alphabetical order(like now)

Comment: @incense_stick I've updated my answer with full solution which you can use in a view.

Comment: The first solution worked, but the second didn't work. Otherwise, thanks a lot!

Comment: I am getting  (2/2) ErrorException

Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: I've updated my answer 3 minutes ago, please check. If you still get the error,, please show me the line where you get it.

Answer (score 1):

In your view instead of using `foreach` use `for` and conditionally check the first letter of every current item with the first character of its previous item:

```
<h4>{{$categories[0]->name[0]}}</h4>
@for($i = 0; $i < count($categories); $i++)
   @if($i > 0 && $categories[$i]->name[0] != $categories[$i-1]->name[0])
    <h4>{{$categories[$i]->name[0]}}</h4>
   @endif
.....
@endfor
```

Another fact used in this solution that you can access a character in a string by its index in that string. i.e we accessed the first character by its index `0` in the category name string.